# 1D array manipulation iteration using loop and switch statement

Tags: c, arrays

This program has multiple options to choose from such as.
1.add element to the array
2.search an element
3.remove an element
I am showing only one case as others are irrelevant. Here 1'st loop works fine for all the options, but for second iteration I can't add a new element, it always says "element added successfully"

```
int k = 0, found = 0;
//k counts the total elements in the list
while(1){
    switch (choice)
    {
      case 1 :

            printf("Enter the number : ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            for(i=0; i<=k; i++){
              if(num == number[i]){
                found=1;
                printf("Element already added. Please try again\n");
                break;
              }
            }
            if(found == 0){
              number[k]=num;
              k = k+1;
              printf("Element added successfully\n");
              found = 0;
            }

    break;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `it doesn't work` mean

Comment: Please show the input, as well as the actual and expected output. "Does not work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Also irrelevant to the problem of it not working I think this program could use some functions to make the code more readable, maybe then You will be able to use the debugger and find the problem yourself.

Comment: `i<=k` --> `i<k` and Need set `found` to `0` before  loop. Also `k < 49` --> `k < 50`

Comment: Please edit the post and indent the code.

Comment: at first using option 1 i can enter data into the array. and using option 3 I can remove the date. but after using option 3 (case 3) when I try to enter a new data using option 1(case 1), it prompts for the input but doesn't add the element into the array and goes back to the beginning of loop(next iteration)

Comment: I am not supposed to use any library function. so I wrote it without functions..

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `found` is set to `0` at the declaration before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the first element your `found` is always `1`. Reset `found` to `0` before the next iteration.

Comment: Set `found` to `0` in the beginning of the `while` loop. When you removed a number successfully `found` is `1` again in the the next adding iteration.

Comment: @surjitsahoo That's because you're not resetting it after deleting an element (nor when searching for an element). Do as Phil says and reset it in the beginning, inside the `while` loop.